# Airflow: Sensor mode='reschedule' gives duplicated logging

Tags: airflow

When I run a sensor in Airflow with `mode='reschedule"` and the sensor executes multiple times because it evaluates to false, the log-texts from previous iterations are repeated.

If the sensor for example iterates three times the log looks like this:

"
*Log-text from iteration 1

Log-text from iteration 1

Log-text from iteration 2

Log-text from iteration 1

Log-text from iteration 2

Log-text from iteration 3*

"

1. Is this the expected behavior or is something misconfigured?
2. Is there any way I can get `mode='reschedule'` to create a log that
   looks like this instead?

*"

Log-text from iteration 1

Log-text from iteration 2

Log-text from iteration 3*

"

I use Airflow 2.2.2 in a configuration run on Azure Container Instances.

## Example

```
file_sensor =  FileSensor(
    task_id = "file_sensor",
    poke_interval = 10 * 60,
    timeout = 60 * 60,
    mode = "reschedule", 
    filepath = "/home/xyz/test"
)
```

---

```
*** Reading remote log from wasb-logsstorage/TestDag/file_sensor/2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00/1.log.
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1241} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1242} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1243} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1262} INFO - Executing <Task(FileSensor): file_sensor> on 2022-01-17 11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 30457 to run task
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'TestDag', 'file_sensor', 'scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '1597', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dags/zz.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpk_5t7u3m', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpbcqgbk_t']
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 1597: Subtask file_sensor
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host localhost
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1429} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=TestDag
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=file_sensor
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {filesystem.py:59} INFO - Poking for file /home/xyz/test
[2022-01-18, 13:45:34 ] {taskinstance.py:1686} INFO - Rescheduling task, marking task as UP_FOR_RESCHEDULE
[2022-01-18, 13:45:34 ] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-01-18, 13:45:34 ] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check

<********** Start of log-text from iteration 2 - (line added manually by Ingesson8) **********>

[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1241} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1242} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1243} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1262} INFO - Executing <Task(FileSensor): file_sensor> on 2022-01-17 11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 30457 to run task
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'TestDag', 'file_sensor', 'scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '1597', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dags/zz.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpk_5t7u3m', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpbcqgbk_t']
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 1597: Subtask file_sensor
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host localhost
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1429} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=TestDag
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=file_sensor
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {filesystem.py:59} INFO - Poking for file /home/xyz/test
[2022-01-18, 13:45:34 ] {taskinstance.py:1686} INFO - Rescheduling task, marking task as UP_FOR_RESCHEDULE
[2022-01-18, 13:45:34 ] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-01-18, 13:45:34 ] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1241} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1242} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1243} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1262} INFO - Executing <Task(FileSensor): file_sensor> on 2022-01-17 11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 32072 to run task
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'TestDag', 'file_sensor', 'scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '1598', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dags/zz.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp1dxahk4f', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmprjw2al9w']
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 1598: Subtask file_sensor
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host localhost
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {taskinstance.py:1429} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=TestDag
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=file_sensor
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {filesystem.py:59} INFO - Poking for file /home/xyz/test
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {taskinstance.py:1686} INFO - Rescheduling task, marking task as UP_FOR_RESCHEDULE
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check

<********** Start of log-text from iteration 3 - (line added manually by Ingesson8) **********>

[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1241} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1242} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1243} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1262} INFO - Executing <Task(FileSensor): file_sensor> on 2022-01-17 11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 30457 to run task
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'TestDag', 'file_sensor', 'scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '1597', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dags/zz.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpk_5t7u3m', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpbcqgbk_t']
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 1597: Subtask file_sensor
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host localhost
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {taskinstance.py:1429} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=TestDag
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=file_sensor
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 13:45:33 ] {filesystem.py:59} INFO - Poking for file /home/xyz/test
[2022-01-18, 13:45:34 ] {taskinstance.py:1686} INFO - Rescheduling task, marking task as UP_FOR_RESCHEDULE
[2022-01-18, 13:45:34 ] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-01-18, 13:45:34 ] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1241} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1242} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1243} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {taskinstance.py:1262} INFO - Executing <Task(FileSensor): file_sensor> on 2022-01-17 11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 32072 to run task
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'TestDag', 'file_sensor', 'scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '1598', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dags/zz.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp1dxahk4f', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmprjw2al9w']
[2022-01-18, 13:55:35 ] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 1598: Subtask file_sensor
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host localhost
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {taskinstance.py:1429} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=TestDag
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=file_sensor
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {filesystem.py:59} INFO - Poking for file /home/xyz/test
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {taskinstance.py:1686} INFO - Rescheduling task, marking task as UP_FOR_RESCHEDULE
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-01-18, 13:55:36 ] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
[2022-01-18, 14:05:38 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 14:05:38 ] {taskinstance.py:1035} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-01-18, 14:05:38 ] {taskinstance.py:1241} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 14:05:38 ] {taskinstance.py:1242} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2022-01-18, 14:05:38 ] {taskinstance.py:1243} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-01-18, 14:05:38 ] {taskinstance.py:1262} INFO - Executing <Task(FileSensor): file_sensor> on 2022-01-17 11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 14:05:38 ] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 1447 to run task
[2022-01-18, 14:05:38 ] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'TestDag', 'file_sensor', 'scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '1600', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dags/zz.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpoq7eudcd', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpqz5eorcr']
[2022-01-18, 14:05:38 ] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 1600: Subtask file_sensor
[2022-01-18, 14:05:38 ] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: TestDag.file_sensor scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host localhost
[2022-01-18, 14:05:39 ] {taskinstance.py:1429} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=TestDag
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=file_sensor
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2022-01-17T11:00:00+00:00
[2022-01-18, 14:05:39 ] {filesystem.py:59} INFO - Poking for file /home/xyz/test
[2022-01-18, 14:05:39 ] {taskinstance.py:1686} INFO - Rescheduling task, marking task as UP_FOR_RESCHEDULE
[2022-01-18, 14:05:39 ] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-01-18, 14:05:39 ] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```